# How to configure and run PHPmailer in PHP

Tags: php

this query may sounds silly but it has become a headache for me. i am using ampps... I need to implement mail notification in my project. i have downloaded the PHPmailer rar file and extracted to my project folder. 
It contains,
*get_oauth_token.php
*src-Exception.php-OAuth.php-PHPMailer.php-POP3.php-SMTP.php
I got only this files in that folder.

```
<?php 
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Here i am getting an error message saying,

> Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Ampps\www\emailpro\email.php on line 8

By googling I got to know that by composer we can download classes. I tried that also. >composer require phpmailer/phpmailer – ERROR- 'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I am totally confused pls anyone tell me how to implement this PHPmailer to the project.

Please help how to configure from scratch i have googled lot and i didnt got the required answer.

Comment: you rather install composer and you it to install dependencies or add your dependencies manually, because now seems that you don't use composer to install dependencies, but trying to include composer autoloader, which logically you don't have. If you installed it manually you need to require phpmailer's autoloader I guess `PHPMailerAutoload.php` not composer's one

Comment: @ArtOsi how can i get Autoload.php now..

Comment: @ArtOsi can u pls guide me whether i need to go manually or i need to install composer. If i can do it manually pls let me know where can i get that dependency files.

Comment: if you talking about `vendor/autoload.php` this file it is generated by composer. If you don't use composer try to use `PHPMailerAutoload.php` instead

Comment: "whether i need to go manually or i need to install composer." it's entirely up to you as to how to manage your application, really.

Comment: @ArtOsi As per the above i have given, PHPMailerAutoload.php . Still i am getting error like this- require(PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream

Comment: you should provide valid path to `PHPMailerAutoload.php` file. If you will `require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php'` it will asume that this file is in same directory as file you are requiring file from, which I believe is not. You should provide full valid path `require 'whatever/file/directory/PHPMailerAutoload.php'`

Comment: @ArtOsi i dont have that file. so i am installing composer now..

Comment: @ArtOsi now i have all files and given correct path. Now for 1st 2 lines - use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; i am getting an error - Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer' not found in.. I used .php extention at last, then i got error like this-  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: @ADyson can u pls help me on the above query

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to install composer then use this code for php mailer to work. It is working in my projects. You can also remove the part of code which you don't need like attachments. One more thing if you want to hide the debugging code errors and notifications remove or comment this line `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`

For more help visit this link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');


    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}`enter code here`
```