# PHPMailer 6 Contact Form with Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer, contacts

I'm trying to make it so that emails can be sent to my Gmail address rather than my domain name email using a PHPMailer form that is in a Bootstrap website. That is my main goal, and the other is to figure out how to have the form include the person's name, email and a subject populate the email rather than the set subject and "no-reply" email.  Any help I could get on this would be great; I thought I would see if anyone wanted to solve this for the community here before I hire a freelancer. Thanks!!

I've tried several tutorials to solve this as well as trying to combine the existing code I'm posting below with the SMTP Gmail version on the PHPMailer Github page ( https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps )but I was not successful, I would instead post the working code here to my domain name email than my failed attempts at sending to Gmail.

```
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">

        <div class="messages"></div>
        <div class="controls">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name." required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email." required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Add your message." rows="4" required="required"></textarea>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" value="Send message">

        </div>

    </form>


<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require './PHPMailer-master/vendor/autoload.php';

$fromEmail = 'noreply@email.com';
$fromName = 'No Reply Email';

$sendToEmail = 'name@mydomain.com';
$sendToName = 'New Website Email Message';

$subject = 'New message from contact form';

$fields = array('name' => 'Name:', 'email' => 'Email:', 'message' => 'Message:');

$okMessage = 'Successfully submitted - we will get back to you soon!';

$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';


error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
    $emailTextHtml .= "<h3>New message from website:</h3><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<table>";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailTextHtml .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    $emailTextHtml .= "</table><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<p>Have a great day!</p>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($sendToEmail, $sendToName);
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);


    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->Body = $emailTextHtml;
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        throw new \Exception('Email send failed. ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}


if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
?>
```

Comment: So what’s your actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working on my projects. You can also remove the part of the code which you don't need like attachments. One more thing if you want to hide the debugging code errors and notifications remove or comment this line $mail->SMTPDebug = 2.
[Check this similar StackOverflow article for more help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886029/how-to-configure-and-run-phpmailer-in-php/54547307#54547307)

If you still need more help to let me know.
Hope this may help you.

```php
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');


    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}`enter code here`
s
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for my form mail, change the variables accordingly.

```
// PHPMailer
require '/var/www/...../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "abcdefgh@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "pppppppppppppppp";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom($Email, $Name);

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo($Email, $Name);

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'Form Mail');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Form Mail";
// END PHP Mailer
$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain';
$mail->isHTML(false);

// $mail->msgHTML("$Message");

$mail->Body = $Message;
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Thank you for sending your message.";
}
```